# Traer datos de la table con where en codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hola amigos resulta que tengo estos datos en la tabla:

[image: tabla]

y con CodeIgniter necesito traer todos los datos del `id_servicio` ingresado.

el código que tengo es este:

En el modelo:

```
 function getcoffeInfo ($id_servicio){
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('id_servicio',$id_servicio);
$query = $this->db->get('Coffemovil');
return $query->row();
}
```

y en controller:

```
    public function getCoffeDate(){

    $new_id = $this->input->post('id_servicio');
    $this->load->model('Model_app');
    $data = $this->Model_app->getcoffeInfo($new_id);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

el problema es que solo me retorna un solo dato y no más, yo los quiero todos los `54` por ejemplo!

[image: return]

Que estoy haciendo mal? saludos.

Comment: El problema es que `$query->row()` solo regresa la primera columna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está aquí:

```
function getcoffeInfo ($id_servicio){
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->where('id_servicio',$id_servicio);
   $query = $this->db->get('Coffemovil');
   return $query->row();
}
```

en la linea:

```
   return $query->row();
```

porque estas retornando solo una fila, debería quedar de este modo:

```
function getcoffeInfo ($id_servicio){
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->where('id_servicio',$id_servicio);
   $query = $this->db->get('Coffemovil');
   return $query->result();
}
```

Si lo que quieres es retornar una fila especifica(la fila 5 por ejemplo), utiliza:

```
 return $query->row(5);
```

[Documentación de CodeIgniter](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html)

Comment: lo había intentado pero retorna: {
  "conn_id": {
    "affected_rows": null,
    "client_info": null,
    "client_version": null,
    "connect_errno": null,
    "connect_error": null,
    "errno": null,
    "error": null,
    "error_list": null,
    "field_count": null,
    "host_info": null,
    "info": null,
    "insert_id": null,
    "server_info": null,
    "server_version": null,
    "stat": null,
    "sqlstate": null,
    "protocol_version": null,
    "thread_id": null,
    "warning_count": null
  },
  "result_id": {
    "current_field": null,
    "fie...

Comment: corregí mi respuesta

Answer (score 1):

con el comando que utilizas solo estas indicandole que te retorne una sola fila...

```
return $query->row();
```

Si en lugar de utilizarlo mejor utilizas result? osea

```
return $query->result();
```

tu codigo se veria algo asi....

```
function getcoffeInfo ($id_servicio){
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->where('id_servicio',$id_servicio);
   $query = $this->db->get('Coffemovil');
   return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo usa al final

```
return $query->getResult()
```